# CakePHP 2: Render as XML doesn't work on web server

Tags: php, xml, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

On my local, everything works fine, I have an xml file generated.
When I put my code on my webserver, it generates a simple text/html file with the xml content visible in the html source code, but the page is not generated as an xml output.

I tried several stuffs I've found here but nothing works.

Any idea ? (Sorry I was not able to format it correctly, link is here: http://pastebin.com/D20JZ5cP)

```php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class RssController extends AppController {
  public $components = array('RequestHandler');
  public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    parent::beforeFilter();
  }
  public function index() {
    $this->response->type('text/xml');
    // $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml');
    // $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'xml');
    // $this->RequestHandler->setContent('xml');
    // $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml');
    // $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'xml');
    $this->channel_properties = array(
      'title' => 'None',
      'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
      'description' => 'None',
    );

    if ( $this->request->query('feed_id') &&
         $this->request->query('user_id') ) {
      $this->loadModel('Feeds');
      $res = $this->Feeds->findAllByFeedIdAndUserAttribution(
               $this->request->query('feed_id'),
               $this->request->query('user_id'));
      if ($res) {
        foreach($res AS $entry) {
          preg_match_all('/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/', $entry['Feeds']['feed'], $matches);
          if (isset($matches[0])) {
            foreach($matches[0] AS $key => $link) {
              if (stripos($link, 'vine.co') !== false) {
                unset($matches[0][$key]);
              }
            }
            $matches[0][] = '[]';
            $entry['Feeds']['feed'] = str_replace($matches[0], '', $entry['Feeds']['feed']);
          }
          $feed[] = array(
            'title' => 'No Name',
            'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
            'description' => $entry['Feeds']['feed'],
            'pubDate' => $entry['Feeds']['date_dt'],
         // 'category' => $entry['Feeds']['date_dt']
          );
        }
        $this->_createFeed($feed);
      }
    }
  }

  private function _createFeed($feed) {
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' . "\n";
    $xml .= '<rss version="2.0"' . $this->xmlns . '>' . "\n";
    // channel required properties
    $xml .= '<channel>' . "\n";
    $xml .= '<title>' . $this->channel_properties["title"] . '</title>' . "\n";
    $xml .= '<link>' . $this->channel_properties["link"] . '</link>' . "\n";
    $xml .= '<description>' . $this->channel_properties["description"] . '</description>' . "\n";
    // channel optional properties
    if (array_key_exists("language", $this->channel_properties)) {
      $xml .= '<language>' . $this->channel_properties["language"] . '</language>' . "\n";
    }
    if (array_key_exists("image_title", $this->channel_properties)) {
      $xml .= '<image>' . "\n";
      $xml .= '<title>' . $this->channel_properties["image_title"] . '</title>' . "\n";
      $xml .= '<link>' . $this->channel_properties["image_link"] . '</link>' . "\n";
      $xml .= '<url>' . $this->channel_properties["image_url"] . '</url>' . "\n";
      $xml .= '</image>' . "\n";
    }
    // get RSS channel items
    // $now = date("YmdHis"); // get current time  
    // configure appropriately to your environment
    foreach ($feed as $rss_item) {
      $xml .= '<item>' . "\n";
      $xml .= '<title>' . $rss_item['title'] . '</title>' . "\n";
      $xml .= '<link>' . $rss_item['link'] . '</link>' . "\n";
      $xml .= '<description><![CDATA[' . ($rss_item['description']) . ']]></description>' . "\n";
      $xml .= '<pubDate>' . $rss_item['pubDate'] . '</pubDate>' . "\n";
      // $xml .= '<category>' . $rss_item['category'] . '</category>' . "\n";
      // $xml .= '<source>' . $rss_item['source'] . '</source>' . "\n";
      if ($this->full_feed) {
        $xml .= '<content:encoded>' . $rss_item['content'] . '</content:encoded>' . "\n";
      }
      $xml .= '</item>' . "\n";
    }
    $xml .= '</channel>';
    $xml .= '</rss>';
    echo $xml;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please review your question, the code doesn't look properly formatted. Also *"I tried several stuffs I've found here but nothing works."* is not a good problem description, it technically says nothing.

Comment: I tried several formatting, without success. The code is here also:  http://pastebin.com/D20JZ5cP

Comment: have you tried validating the XML you create and throwing an exception if invalid so that you can ensure to only provide valid XML? As I wrote creating the XML by concatenating strings is prone to error especially as you inject data that you do not XML encode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works on both ... With several tries...

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('Xml', 'Lib');

class RssController extends AppController {

public $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
}

public function index() {

    $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml');

    $this->channel_properties = array(
        'title' => 'None',
        'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
        'description' => 'None',
    );

    if ($this->request->query('feed_id') && $this->request->query('user_id')) {
        $this->loadModel('Feeds');
        $res = $this->Feeds->findAllByFeedIdAndUserAttribution($this->request->query('feed_id'), $this->request->query('user_id'));
        if ($res) {
            foreach($res AS $entry) {
                preg_match_all('/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/', $entry['Feeds']['feed'], $matches);
                if (isset($matches[0])) {
                    foreach($matches[0] AS $key => $link) {
                        if (stripos($link, 'vine.co') !== false) {
                            unset($matches[0][$key]);
                        }
                    }
                    $matches[0][] = '[]';
                    $entry['Feeds']['feed'] = str_replace($matches[0], '', $entry['Feeds']['feed']);
                }

                $feeds[] = array(
                    'title' => 'No Name',
                    'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
                    'description' => $entry['Feeds']['feed'],
                    'pubDate' => $entry['Feeds']['date_dt'],
//                      'category' => $entry['Feeds']['date_dt']
                );
            }

            $res = $this->_createFeed($feeds);
            $this->set('feeds', $res);
        }
    }
}

private function _createFeed($feed) {

    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' . "\n";

    $xml .= '<rss version="2.0"' . $this->xmlns . '>' . "\n";

    // channel required properties
    $xml .= '<channel>' . "\n";
    $xml .= '<title>' . $this->channel_properties["title"] . '</title>' . "\n";
    $xml .= '<link>' . $this->channel_properties["link"] . '</link>' . "\n";
    $xml .= '<description>' . $this->channel_properties["description"] . '</description>' . "\n";

    // channel optional properties
    if (array_key_exists("language", $this->channel_properties)) {
        $xml .= '<language>' . $this->channel_properties["language"] . '</language>' . "\n";
    }
    if (array_key_exists("image_title", $this->channel_properties)) {
        $xml .= '<image>' . "\n";
        $xml .= '<title>' . $this->channel_properties["image_title"] . '</title>' . "\n";
        $xml .= '<link>' . $this->channel_properties["image_link"] . '</link>' . "\n";
        $xml .= '<url>' . $this->channel_properties["image_url"] . '</url>' . "\n";
        $xml .= '</image>' . "\n";
    }

    // get RSS channel items
//      $now = date("YmdHis"); // get current time  // configure appropriately to your environment

    foreach ($feed as $rss_item) {
        $xml .= '<item>' . "\n";
        $xml .= '<title>' . $rss_item['title'] . '</title>' . "\n";
        $xml .= '<link>' . $rss_item['link'] . '</link>' . "\n";
        $xml .= '<description><![CDATA[' . ($rss_item['description']) . ']]></description>' . "\n";
        $xml .= '<pubDate>' . $rss_item['pubDate'] . '</pubDate>' . "\n";
//          $xml .= '<category>' . $rss_item['category'] . '</category>' . "\n";
//          $xml .= '<source>' . $rss_item['source'] . '</source>' . "\n";

        if ($this->full_feed) {
            $xml .= '<content:encoded>' . $rss_item['content'] . '</content:encoded>' . "\n";
        }

        $xml .= '</item>' . "\n";
    }

    $xml .= '</channel>';

    $xml .= '</rss>';

    return $xml;
}

}
```